# Hide css class using jquery

Tags: jquery

i would like to remove a css class with jquery. I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

const datacount = $('#datacount')
const badge = datacount.parent('.badge')

const config = {
  url: 'controllers/ctrl_admin_view_notification.php',
  success (res) {
    if (Number(res)) {
      datacount.text(res)
      badge.show() 

    } else {
      badge.hide()

    }
  },
  error () {
    badge.hide()
  }
}

$.ajax(config)
window.setInterval($.ajax, 100000, config)

});
```

And this is my html code:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">

<i class="icon-bell"></i>
<span class="badge badge-success"><div id="datacount"></div></span>
</a>
```

It works fine but the only problem is when i refresh the page if there are no values in the database i can see a green dot flashing for a second and i think it is caused by the class .badge-success
So i thought maybe to create a new class and call it .hidden

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

An then insert the class inside the html code

```
<span class="badge badge-success hidden"><div id="datacount"></div</span>
```

I have tried to remove the hidden class using jquery but it doesn't work, maybe somebody could help me?

Many thanks

Comment: So  $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden"); does not work?

Comment: did you try `$(selector).removeClass("hidden")`

Comment: Hi i've tried with removeClass and it works but it doesn't format css properly and the result is a horrible icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `style="display: none;"` because jquery's show and hide method use the display property to show and hide elements. They do it by applying it as an inline style.

Inline styles normally override CSS styles so your initial answer should have worked, unless you had set !important or were using boilerplate that also had a hidden class that had !important.

Comment: Hi, it worked simply adding <span style="display: none;" class="badge badge-success"><div id="datacount"></div></span>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `datacount.parent().removeClass("hidden")` https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

And in your row 
`<span class="badge badge-success hidden"><div id="datacount"></div</span>` 
you have error with closed tag `div`. Fix it maybe it's problem
Right format:
`<span class="badge badge-success hidden"><div id="datacount"></div></span>`